# GridBagLayout labels are overlapping

Tags: java

My last two labels are overlapping and I cannot figure out why. I do not think anything in the grid is overlapping I drew it out. 'Right' is the name of the GridBagLayout panel. It works as intended if I get rid of the last two labels and assign 1 to weightx and weighty for chickenCostLabel.

```
    JLabel chickenLabel = new JLabel();
    chickenLabel.setText("Chicken");
    gbc3.gridx = 0;
    gbc3.gridy = 1;
    gbc3.weighty = 0;
    gbc3.weightx = 0;
    right.add(chickenLabel, gbc3);

    chickenCountLabel = new JLabel();
    chickenCountLabel.setText("Count: ");
    gbc3.gridx = 0;
    gbc3.gridy = 2;
    gbc3.weighty = 0;
    gbc3.weightx = 0;
    right.add(chickenCountLabel, gbc3);

    chickenCostLabel = new JLabel();
    chickenCostLabel.setText("Cost: ");
    gbc3.gridx = 0;
    gbc3.gridy = 3;
    gbc3.weighty = 0;
    gbc3.weightx = 0;
    right.add(chickenCostLabel, gbc3);

    JButton chickenButton = new JButton();
    chickenButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
    gbc3.gridx = 1;
    gbc3.gridy = 1;
    gbc3.gridheight = 3;
    gbc3.weighty = 0;
    gbc3.weightx = 0;
    chickenButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            queueBuyNum.add(1);
        }
    });
    right.add(chickenButton, gbc3);

    JLabel blobLabel = new JLabel();
    blobLabel.setText("Blob");
    gbc3.gridx = 0;
    gbc3.gridy = 4;
    gbc3.weighty = 0;
    gbc3.weightx = 0;
    right.add(blobLabel, gbc3);

    blobCountLabel = new JLabel();
    blobCountLabel.setText("Count: ");
    gbc3.gridx = 0;
    gbc3.gridy = 5;
    gbc3.weighty = 1;
    gbc3.weightx = 1;
    right.add(blobCountLabel, gbc3);
```

Comment: are you using any ide like netbeans? or trying on your own

Comment: I would suggest go with netbeans as it is really easy and have more features than that.And you can design you gui within minutes..

Comment: alright ill give it a go

Comment: I think you need to set weightx and weighty for other labels too (similar to  the last one) See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html

Comment: I run it and the labels are not overlapping. maybe you set to small size of the right Panel or your frame? could you please add to your code more details about it?